# Router Outlet and html issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to do some angular routing inside my application containing children routes and I seem to be coming across an issue.

I have my Routes set up:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'settings', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, children: [
    { path: 'document', component: DocumentComponent }
  ]}
];
```

The inside my `app.component` I have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

So when the application loads the SettingsComponent successfully loads which contains the following HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button routerLink="./document">Document Manager</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Pack Manager</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Email Manager</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>SMS Manager</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The issue is when I click on the Document Manager button I want the SettingsComponent HTML to go and be replaced with the DocumentComponent.

The HTML seems to stay and the DocumentComponent HTML gets added below which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'settings', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
  { path: 'settings/document', component: DocumentComponent }
];
```